# Definite Integral Evaluation Undefined

Tags: definite-integrals

We have $$ f(x) := \frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}, \qquad x \ne 0$$

We need to determine a number $a<0$ such that $$ 
\int^0_a f(x)\, dx = f(a). $$

What I tried:

With the substitution technique I get to 
$[-e^{1/x}]^0_a$. So that means we would get $-e^{1/0} + e^{1/a}$, but $1/0$ is undefined, so how do I continue?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}=0.$

Comment: the indefinite integral of $\int\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}dx=-e^{1/x}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that your function $f$ is not defined at 0, hence you may not apply the fundamental theorem on $[a,0]$. But if you recall that 
$$ \int_a^0 f(x) \, dx = \lim_{b \nearrow 0} \int_a^b f(x)\, dx $$
you get, by the fundamental theorem 
$$ \int_a^0 f(x)\, dx = \lim_{b\nearrow 0} -e^{1/b} + e^{1/a} = e^{1/a} $$
I'm sure, you can continue from here.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have one question: what does the ''weird'' symbol mean? I am not familiar with that one yet. It looks like a damaged arrow.

Comment: $b \nearrow 0$? $b \to 0$ with only considering values of $b < 0$.